# Querying multiple columns in a database and finding their sum

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have school application data-table that looks like this...

```
create table todel (user_id int, SchemesApplicable1 int, SchemesApplicable2 int, 
SchemesApplicable3 int, SchemesApplicable4 int);

insert into todel values (1, 1, 0, 1, 0);

insert into todel values (2, 0, 0, 0, 0);

insert into todel values (3, 1, 0, 1, 0);

insert into todel values (4, 1, 0, 0, 0);

insert into todel values (5, 1, 0, 1, 1);

    SELECT Count(User_Id) as No_Off_Application , 
 sum(if(SchemesApplicable1 = 1, 1, 0)) as first,
sum(if(SchemesApplicable2 = 1, 1, 0))  as second, 
sum(if(SchemesApplicable3 = 1, 1, 0))  as third, 
sum(if(SchemesApplicable4 = 1, 1, 0))  as forth 
FROM todel
```

The above query will return a report like this...

```
No_Off_Application  first   second  third   forth
5   4   0   3   1
```

I will like to add one more column with the applicants who have applied for more than one scheme.
The expected count is 3 (user id's 1, 3 and 5) 
How do I write a query for this?

Comment: What does this have to do with pandas?

Comment: I just wanted to know how pandas would handle this

Comment: Well, there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Count(User_Id) as No_Off_Application , 
       sum(SchemesApplicable1) as first,
       sum(SchemesApplicable2) as second,
       sum(SchemesApplicable3) as third,
       sum(SchemesApplicable4) as forth,
       sum(SchemesApplicable1 + SchemesApplicable2 + SchemesApplicable3 + SchemesApplicable4 >= 1) as users_at_least_with_one_application
FROM todel
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the setup for Pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
                   [2, 0, 0, 0, 0,], 
                   [3, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
                   [4, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
                   [5, 1, 0, 1, 1]], 
              columns=['user_id', 'Scheme1', 'Scheme2', 'Scheme3', 'Scheme4'])
print(df)

   user_id  Scheme1  Scheme2  Scheme3  Scheme4
0        1        1        0        1        0
1        2        0        0        0        0
2        3        1        0        1        0
3        4        1        0        0        0
4        5        1        0        1        1
```

Using pandas, to check the total number of schemes per user, you'd use `df.sum(axis=1)`:

```
print(df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(1))

0    2
1    0
2    2
3    1
4    3
dtype: int64
```

To just get the `user_ids`, you can use boolean indexing:

```
user_id_ser = df.user_id[df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(1) > 1]
print(user_id_ser)

0    1
2    3
4    5
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
```

To add a "Flag/Indicator" column, you'll need to create a mask using `> 1` and convert to integer using `df.astype`:

```
df['Schemes > 1'] = (df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(1) > 1).astype(int)
print(df)

   user_id  Scheme1  Scheme2  Scheme3  Scheme4  Schemes > 1
0        1        1        0        1        0            1
1        2        0        0        0        0            0
2        3        1        0        1        0            1
3        4        1        0        0        0            0
4        5        1        0        1        1            1
```

Lastly, to get your exact output, you can use `df.where`:

```
print(df.where(df > 0).count())

user_id        5
Scheme1        4
Scheme2        0
Scheme3        3
Scheme4        1
Schemes > 1    3
dtype: int64
```